# How to trigger different functions when the mouse is scrolled up and scrolled down

Tags: reactjs, scroll, mouseevent

I have two functions zoomin and zoomout.I want to trigger zoomin when scrolled up and zoomout when scrolled down.onwheel does not provide up and down feature

```
 onWheel={()=>this.zoomIn()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it from `event.deltaY`

```
onWheel={(e)=>this.zoomState(e)}
```

```
  zoomState(e) {
    switch (e.deltaY > 0) {
      case true:
        this.zoomIn();
        break;
      default:
        this.zoomOut();
    }
  }
```

Comment: The solution is fine. But using arrow function inside a prop is not encouraged. As each time the component re-rendered and every time the function will be generated.

Comment: Yes you can `bind ` it in the constructor if performance is your first concern. I just used method that was provided.